# Android Socket.IO timeouts and cannot create a connection

Tags: android, socket.io

Okay, so I've a server with IP: `38.66.221.111`
And Server PORT: `52323`

At first, I wanted to check if socket is available on server side, so I downloaded `Termius` application to test it:

So I added IP address `38.66.221.111`, checked "TELNET" and added port `52323` and connection was made successful.

Then I went to my Android application and tried to do the socket connection using `nkzawa` library for sockets.

Code looks like this:

```
try {
     socket = IO.socket("http://38.66.221.111:52323")

     socket.apply {
        on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect)
        on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect)
        on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError)
        on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectTimeout)
    }
} catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

From logs received, all I got is `onConnectError` and `onConnectTimeout` callback. Why is it working on Termius, but not on my app?

`com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.SocketIOException: timeout` is received in onConnectError callback.

Library that I'm using:

```
implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0', {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
})
```

**WHAT HAVE NOT WORKED FOR ME**:

- Added network permission
- Disabled timeout with `socket.io().timeout(-1)`

Comment: Try to disable timeout with this **socket.io().timeout(-1)** and make sure you have internet permission.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule Thanks for suggestions. I did both and nothing changed. If I disable timeout, I do not receive onError/onTimeout callbacks, but then again, I do not receive onConnect as well, so it just hides the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried connecting on another network?

Comment: I just understood that my server is TCP based and not HTTP, so that kinda makes sense, right, as nkzawa library is for web sockets only?